# rostest - Minimum Working Example

Tags: ros, catkin, rostest, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having problems developing tests for a package with catkin, specifically tests that run within a launch file using C++/gtest.

You can download my files [here](http://cse.wustl.edu/%7Edvl1/davidscheck.zip).

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(davidscheck)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)

catkin_package()

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

find_package(rostest REQUIRED)
find_package(gtest)

add_rostest_gtest(tests_mynode test/alaunch.launch test/mytest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tests_mynode ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})
```

test/alaunch.launch

```
<launch>
 <test test-name="test_mynode" pkg="davidscheck" type="test_mynode" />
</launch>
```

teset/mytest.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(DavidsTester, basicTest){
  EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

**Problem**: The executable is not being built.

Note that I do want it to run within the launch file, so adding `catkin_add_gtest` will not work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/181708/rostest---minimum-working-example/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-07-01**:
It just doesn't even try to build the executable? Or the build fails?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-07-01**:
Did you pass `run_tests` as a make target when building?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-01**:
Slight correction: The executable is being built, but the launch file cannot find it. Output snippet is here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JVV8QfXA .

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-01**:
(compiled with run_tests)

**Comment by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on 2015-01-06**:
I cannot run your example with indigo. CMake cannot find the package gtest:
"Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gtest""

If I remove it, I get no error. But if I remove your package from my workspace I get the error "Unknown CMake command "add_rostest_gtest"". What do I miss?

**Comment by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on 2015-01-06**:
The answer to my own question is "find_package(rostest REQUIRED)"

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-01-06**:
You should also wrap all testing stuff in a conditional block as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your node is called "tests_mynode" (with an S on test) and the launch file loads type "test_mynode" (no S). Fix the launch and all worked on my system under hydro.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-01**:
Fair enough. :)

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-02-01**:
Full minimum working example here: https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/simple_rostest

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-05-16**:
@VictorLamoine under what license do you distribute the example code?

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-05-17**:
@thinwybk BSD, https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/simple_rostest/blob/kinetic/package.xml#L8.
Do whatever you want it with!

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-05-17**:
@VictorLamoine Great. Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [gocarlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/21835/gocarlos/) on 2017-10-03**:
here another example: https://github.com/gocarlos/ros_unit_tests_example

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another side note: your CMakeLists.txt file should look more like this:

```
if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  find_package(rostest REQUIRED)
  add_rostest_gtest(tests_mynode test/alaunch.launch test/mytest.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(tests_mynode ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-01**:
A fair point. I took it out because I wanted it to build more, not less.